# Get all revision log from a Branch in SVN using SVNKIT

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am trying to fetch all activity that has been performed on a branch in my Java code using SVN Kit.

```
SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnURL);
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("UserName", "password");
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
Collection logEntries = repository.log(new String[] { "" }, null, 0, -1, true, true);
```

The above code works like a charm and I am getting all activity on the Branch denoted by my svnURL attribute.

But the real problem comes in when after some activity the branch itself was renamed. For example

```
Initial Branch => https://domain/repository/branches/OriginalName
New
Branch =>  https://domain/repository/branches/NewName
```

Now, after the rename has happened, when I run the above code using the Old Name, I get a propfind error that says, the file cannot be located. But when I run with the new branch name, everything works file and it also gives the activity logs on that branch but only until the rename. The activity that had happened on the OldBranch name is not returned.

Is there a way in SVNKit to get the output as I am expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the the parameter [strictNode](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html#log%28java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.util.Collection,%20long,%20long,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) of `log` to true

> If strictNode is true, copy history will not be traversed (if any
>   exists) when harvesting the revision logs for each path.

This seems to be equivalent of stop on copy/rename in most GUIs. By setting it to false you should get the whole revision history.

**Note:** `svn rename` is just a [copy and delete](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re18.html). It will create a new copy of the file/folder and delete the old one.

Comment: Actually. This is something that I just tried. The problem here that I am seeing is that the SVNKit ends up returning me all activity. i.e. the results would also include any activity that might have had happened on /trunk or on any other branch between the date range. Which is Something that I dont want. Can this be a bug in SVNKit?

Comment: @SalmanA.Kagzi strange, it definitely should work: http://old.nabble.com/What-is-ancestor-log-history%3A-SVNRepository.log%28%29--td32571191.html

Comment: Thanks for that link. This actually proves my result right? What I mean is, when i have the strictNode as false, the logs goes back to the inception of each files i.e. when those files were actually added (in trunk or in any other branch). But I don't want to go that far. I only want to go as far as when that branch was created. Is there any way to limit that? Thanks again.

Comment: the problem is that the creation of the branch is the same as the renaming, it is only a copy. SVN can't distinct those. It seems that you would have to provide the starting revision of the branch. SVN can't know where to stop the logs here.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have been doing more investigation for this problem. It seems that there is no direct way we can get that kind of logs. Is there any way in which we can access the branch using the Old Name? What I mean is, from above example, can I access  https://domain/repository/branches/OriginalName branch after it has been renamed? And how can I do that using SVN Kit.

Comment: you can't do that :( It is not visible anymore.

Comment: Thats bad :( Is there a way through which we can get only Copy Activity on a branch? I haven't found anything so far. I hope its not a NO again. :(

Comment: On further investigation, I saw that the way SVN handles renames (at any level i.e. branch or directory or file) is that it deletes the Old entry and adds a new One with a Copy path as the path of the Old entry. Is this a correct deduction? and is this true with all Versions of SVN or is it something specific to only the new ones?

Comment: [it is svn standard](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re18.html). A move/rename is a copy and then delete the old.

Comment: Thanks man. I am planning to first identify the old names of the branch from the logs that I get. Will identify Old name where a commit as 2 changed paths, 1 added and another deleted. And Copy path of the added item is equal to the Path of the deleted one. Will use these paths to match them with the File names that I get from the logs to identify if the entry is an interested one or not.